# Store locator API for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios5

I was browsing through some applications for the iPhone with a store locator in them allowing users to find stores based on a zip code or current location.

I was wondering if there is any way to find an XML/JSON file which lists all the address for a particular store (Walmart, Target, etc...) which I could extract using the NSXML parser and then corelate the address to the MapView. Do I have to make use of Google Maps API?

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at the Foursquare Search API: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search

Otherwise it might be worth making a manually defined list of stores that the user can chose from and manually adding an XML/JSON store list to your bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Actually There Are so many API Available Today Like `FourSquare Google Places Search API` etc.

I think You should Use Google Places Search API for That.It Gives More detailed Data Comparatively To Others.They Have Great documentation for The Same.
[Here you should go For The Google Places Search API.](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search)

[Go For The FourSquare API.](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search)